# Bootstrap 4.0.0-Beta 2 Navbar Multi-Column Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a navbar based on Bootstrap 4.0.0-Beta 2 wherein the elements are right-aligned. One of the elements is a multi-column dropdown. I got as far as the code below (from bootstrap's website), but I can't seem to make it look right when in full page view. The dropdown is not showing properly as I would have wanted. You can see for yourself if you try the snippet.

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Navbar</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </head>
      <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
   <div class="container container-sm">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link6</a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 7</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 8</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 9</a>
     </div>     
    </div>
   </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Navbar</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </head>
      <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" style="width:300px" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
   <div class="container container-sm">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link6</a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 7</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 8</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 9</a>
     </div>     
    </div>
   </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks.. that's a quick solution.. I have a follow-up question though, how do I show the dropdown menu from the dropdown heading going to the left side? Not like how it is now where the menu is showing more to the right

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Navbar</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-sm-between flex-column flex-sm-row">
                    <div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link6</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 7</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 8</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 9</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain where was a mistake in template.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Not to me to users who will read your answer. Edit answer and repair it. Explain in words and code.